# Hive out-of-the-box json parser

Tags: java, json, hadoop, hive

I have a text file containing json records I would like to load to Hive. My json looks like:

```
{"vr":1,"tm":1312816191516,"tms":"08-08-2011 15:09:51.516 GMT","as":1002,"pb":1102,"cts":[1204,1205],"ctgs":[1304,1305],"op":1400,"ev":2,"dv":1503,"dvgs":[1605,1606],"cnt":"cnt5","usr":"usr8","atts":[{"id":8002,"val":"ccc"},{"id":8003,"val":"ddd"}],"sel":{"cm":2102,"ty":"PRE","ag":3002,"ad":4002,"fl":5002,"fla":6002,"hg":7002,"mc":"WAP","pr":0.1}}
```

As you can see I have a nested json with arrays of primitives and array of objects.

Is it possible to load it as is to Hive using any built in function?

Yosi

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to load it into Hive as is.
It's possible you may need to escape the `"`s. I haven't loaded JSON into hive, so not 100% if any escaping needs to be done.

To access the JSON elements once it is in hive; Hive has a built in function for doinh so. `get_json_object`, which can be seen in details at
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-getjsonobject

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom serde to read json files to hive tables. See the following serde on github -
https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde

Answer (score 1):

Also checkout the **brickhouse** - https://github.com/klout/brickhouse.
They have quite decent UDF's for json (like json_split and json_map).
With brickhouse and get_json_object / json_tuple (also mentioned by Nija here) you can even avoid using custom SerDe's, like Hive-JSON-Serde.